# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

Hi I am trying to invoke a url using JQUery with parameters appended to it. The values of the parameters are from the text fields in the dialog box on the page.  When I invoke the url with no values filled in the parameter (i.e url inside if) it execute fine, but when I enter values in the dialog box and run it gives me groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.
I alert the url in both cases and the values are displayed appropriately.
I am also handling the 3 params accordingly in the controller def runUserReport
Here is the code Snippet

```
 function runJasperReport() {  
var myurl="";  
var from_date=$('#from_date').val();  
var to_date=$('#to_date').val();  
var user_id=$('#user_id').val();  
if(!from_date ||!to_date ||!user_id)  
                                   {  
                        myurl='/gra/reports/runUserReport?fromdate=&todate=&userid=';  
                    }  
                    else{  
                        myurl='/gra/reports/runUserReport?fromdate='+from_date+'&todate='+to_date+'&userid='+user_id+'';  
                           }  
   alert(myurl);  
jQuery.ajax({  
      url: myurl,  
      dataType: 'html',  
      timeout: 3000,  
      beforeSend: function() {  
          jQuery('#demo').html('<center><div style="width: 70px; height: 100px; display: inline-block;margin-top: 120px;"></div></center>')
      },
      success:function(data,textStatus){  
          jQuery('#demo').html(data);  
      },  
      error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}  
  });  
  return false;
```

Error Received:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: gra.ReportsController.$() is applicable for argument types: (gra.ReportsController$_closure8_closure9)   values: [gra.ReportsController$_closure8_closure9@22d90078]  
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), any(g
roovy.lang.Closure), getG(), wait()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request to the URL

`/gra/reports/runUserReport`

is telling grails that there should be a `reportsController` with a method `runUserReport` on it.  However, grails is saying that the url is calling for the method `$()`, i.e. so your request looks like

`/gra/reports/$()`

Something is happening between when you set the url and fire the request.  Look in webkit/firebug and the ajax that gets sent and verify that the url is what you think it is.